# how to prevent host header injection in struts2 (JAVA) (Jboss-as-7.2.0.Final)

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jboss7.x, hostheaders

I'm just trying to find the solution for host header injection but couldn't find it. Need help from you techies.

Using struts2 as a framework, jsp as frontend and jboss 7 as an application server .

Below are the sample request,

`GET /xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxMaster.action HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8444
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8444/xxxxx/xxxxx.action
Cookie: menusToExpand=LINKID000001323Menu%2CLINKID000041521Menu%2CLINKID000055923Menu%2CLINKID000042954Menu%2CLINKID000094209Menu; itemToHighlight=https%3A//xxx.xxx.xx.xxx%3A8444/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx.action; JSESSIONID=qKGED+F7LXZ1hvQijXKO+5Qp.hellnode01
Connection: keep-alive`

I want to hide host ip address to prevent Host Header Injection..

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: You could remove it with a normal filter if your app doesn't rely on it (I don't know if S2 uses it to construct links or not) or just filter it through a whitelist of allowed host names.

Comment: Okay I'll handle this using filter. Thanks :)